# Chaining multiple assertions together

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert

Is the following considered bad practice or not pythonic:

```
assert (isinstance(from_, Component) and isinstance(to_, Component) and...)
```

That is, is each assertion supposed to only contain one unit, like:

```
assert isinstance(from_, Component)
assert isinstance(to_, Component)
# etc
```

Comment: Don't you want to know which condition failed?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes, that's a good point -- that was what I was looking for with the question.